# How can I render a list of search results?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm really stumped as to what is going on. I reviewed videos on map, arrow functions and implicit returns but still have no idea why my code is not making sense. When I console log everything it is fine, all the data is there. However, when I try to output the data into a div or list, nothing renders. What gives?

Here is the code in question:

```js
const renderSearchResults = () => {
  if (this.state.searchResults) {
    Object.keys(this.state.searchResults).map((key) => {
      console.log(this.state.searchResults[key]);
      return <div>{this.state.searchResults[key].Title}</div>;
    });
  } else {
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
  }
};
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot to `return Object.keys...`?

Comment: thanks, i'm an idiot.

Comment: No you're not! :)

Answer (score 1):

`Object.keys(this.state.searchResults).map()` creates a new array but you need to return it in your `renderSearchResults()`

```
return Object.keys(this.state.searchResults).map((key) => {
   ...
```